# How to trigger updates to the yaml-files?

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-assistant

I'm a web developer with 10 years' experience who just started looking into home automation.

I'm trying to figure out how to shorten the feedback loop while setting up my system. Currently, the best thing I got for updating is rebooting my Raspberry with `sudo shutdown -r now`.

I have tried calling the service `homeassistant/reload_core_config`, but nothing seems to happen, when I for example add an option to this input:

```
input_select:
  lullaby:
    name: Lullaby
    options:
      - Rain
      - Babbling Brook
      - None
    initial: None
    icon: mdi:weather-rainy
```

You are suppose to be able to restart the system with this: `sudo systemctl stop home-assistant@pi`
but I get this error: 
`Failed to stop home-assistant@pi.service: Unit home-assistant@pi.service not loaded.`

My ideal solution would be to trigger an update every time I upload a file over SSL to the server to the `/.homeassistant` folder.

Comment: Do you get better answers from https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @mico you think so?

Comment: There people are more code oriented.

Comment: Your question seems too code / config oriented compared to those that get answers here. I would suggest repost.

Answer (score 6):

Your command seems to be out of sync with the rest.

```
sudo systemctl stop home-assistant@pi
```

First it seems incomplete at the end at best and moreover why are you using *stop* to *restart*? Why not use *restart*.

```
sudo systemctl restart home-assistant@pi.service
```

Answer (score 2):

Apperently this is the systemctl that was being used by raspbian

home-assistant@homeassistant.service